# How to match words that doesn't start nor end with certain characters using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, unity-game-engine, match

I want to find word matches that doesn't start nor end with some specific characters.

For example, I have this input and I only want to match the highlighted word:

> "string" **string** 'string'

And exclude other words that start and end with either **"** or **'**.

I am currently using this pattern:

[image]

But I do not know what pattern I should use that would exclude words that start and end with some specified characters.

Can some one give me some advice on what pattern I should use? Thank you

Comment: `(?<!")\bstring\b(?!")`

Comment: That works great, thank you!

Comment: (?<!")\bstring\b(?!") will still match 'string' when i tested it.

Comment: @siggi_pop you're right, oversight - resolved in my answer.

Comment: Exclude which words ? English language words ? Regex can't match language words.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you're currently using matches since `\b` properly asserts the positions between `"s` and `g"` (a position between a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non-word character). You can use one of the following methods:

1. Negate specific characters (negative lookbehind/lookahead)

   - This method allows you to specify a character, set of characters, or substring to negate from a match.
   - `(?<!['"])\bstring\b(?!['"])` - [see it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Nb97sb/1)

     - `(?<!['"])` - ensure `"` doesn't precede.
     - `(?!['"])` - ensure `"` doesn't proceeds.
2. Allow specific characters (positive lookbehind/lookahead)

   - This method allows you to specify a character, set of characters, or substring to ensure match.
   - `(?<=\s|^)\bstring\b(?=\s|$)` - [see it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Nb97sb/2)

     - `(?<=\s|^)` - ensure whitespace or the beginning of the line precedes.
     - `(?=\s|$)` - ensure whitespace or the end of the line proceeds.
3. A combination of both above

   - This method allows you to negate specific cases while allowing others (not commonly used and not really needed for the problem presented, but may be useful to you or others.
   - Something like `(?<=\s|^)string(?!\s+(?!stop)|$)` would ensure the word isn't followed by the word `stop`
   - Something like `(?<=(?<!stop\s*)\s+|^)string(?=\s+|$)` would ensure the word doesn't follow the word `stop` - note that quantifiers (`\s+`) in lookbehinds are not allowed in most regex engines, .NET allows it.
   - Something like `(?<=\s|^)\bstring\b(?=\s|$)(?!\z)` would ensure a the word isn't at the end of the string (different from end of line if multi-line).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thank you for catching that - it's now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will pick *string* if it is between spaces: `\sstring\s`

```
var sample = "\"string\" string \"string\" astring 'string_ string?string string ";
var regx = new Regex(@"\sstring\s");
var matches = regx.Matches(sample);
foreach (Match mt in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{mt.Value} {mt.Index,3} {mt.Length,3}");
}
```

Comment: Though this doesn't really answer the question which was basically how to find all that are not wrapped in `"` or `'`. OP didn't say e.g. `astring` should not be found. Also word at the beginning or end of the string without a leading or trailing space would get excluded here